# What ASP classic code can I use to print the ASP version?

Tags: asp-classic

I have taken on a new ASP classic project and I don't have much experience with ASP. I want the code I can use to print the ASP version - so that I know which exact docs to look at.

Comment: Pretty sure anything classic asp these days is 3.0 if its even used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Citing from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_scriptengine.asp), you can determine the actual running version with these functions:

```vb
response.write(ScriptEngine & "<br />")
response.write(ScriptEngineBuildVersion & "<br />")
response.write(ScriptEngineMajorVersion & "<br />")
response.write(ScriptEngineMinorVersion)
```

Comment: That gives you to the Scripting Engine versions *(VBScript, JScript etc)* not the Classic ASP ISAPI filter version. This also works client side because it's part of the scripting runtime independent of server side components.

Comment: I don't see a reason for the downvote, because it is not exactly clear, which version the OP intends to get. Either way, it's highly improbable, the version matters, since the latest change to the ASP engine is like 15 years ago. :)

Comment: <%
response.write "<pre>" & ScriptEngine & " " & ScriptEngineMajorVersion & "." & ScriptEngineMinorVersion & " build " & ScriptEngineBuildVersion & "</pre>" %>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is such a thing, I've always used the version of IIS the server is running to determine the version of Classic ASP installed.

From the [Wikipedia article - Active Server pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages)

> - ASP 1.0 was released on December 1996 as part of IIS 3.0
> - ASP 2.0 was released on September 1997 as part of IIS 4.0
> - ASP 3.0 was released on November 2000 as part of IIS 5.0

If you are running IIS 5.0 or higher then ASP 3.0 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("server_software")) %>
```